# Is there a difference between viscous flow and plasticity?

Tags: crystal-plasticity

Jargon is quite confusing when dealing with viscoelasticity, plasticity, and anelasticity.

In a general constant stress creep curve: there is instantaneous elastic strain, followed by time-dependent anelastic strain, and then a constant strain-rate viscous flow type behavior until the stress is removed. In general, the elastic and anelastic strains are recovered, but the constant strain-rate deformation stays after removing the load.

In this description, does it mean that the constant strain-rate deformation represents plasticity? I'm not sure how to define plasticity accurately in this context. I know that the entire curve represents a viscoelastic behavior, but does the viscous flow represents plasticity?

Any insights or clarification on the differences will be much appreciated! I couldn't find a text that explain this thoroughly.